# Efficiently computing a dataframe column containing the column names with value greater than a percentile

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe with a large number of integer columns

```
df

id    col_1    col_2   ...    col_n
0     1        21             120 
1     2        42             23
2     55       16             54
3     4        48             12
4     12       100            75
5     6        52             64
```

and would like to generate an additional column (say `my_col`) containing the column names of values that are above the 90th percentile

```
df

id    col_1    col_2   ...    col_n    my_col
0     1        21             120      [col_n] # because 120 is above the 90th percentile of values in col_n
1     2        42             23       [] # empty list because no values are above the 90th percentile in their respective cols
2     55       16             120      [col_1, col_n] # because 55 is above the 90th percentile in col_1, and 120 is in col_n
3     4        48             12       []
4     12       100            75       [col_2]
5     6        52             64       []
```

I first create a dataframe with the 90th percentile for all columns:

```
#cols = my column names list
#transposing to pretty print it a bit more nicely, don't think it's strictly necessary
df_p90 = df[cols].quantile([0.90]).transpose()
```

Then I define a custom function to calculate the desired list of columns:

```
def f(row, df_quantiles, in_cols):
    col_list = []
    for col in in_cols:
        if row[col] > df_quantiles.at[col, 0.90]:
            col_list.append(col)
    return col_list
```

And apply it to my dataframe

```
df["my_col"] = df.apply(f, args=(df_p90, cols), axis=1)
```

The code works fine, but runs really slowly when I run it on a large dataframe (something like 200000 rows and 2000 columns). I'm pretty sure it's because of how I defined `f` via the for loop and direct lookup with `at`. I can't really "think dataframes" and I'm very much tightened to "everything is for-loops and if-then-elses".

How can I do something better?

Comment: Maybe sort your columns. Then once you find a column not meeting 90th percentile you can discard the remaining unchecked ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try `dot`

```
df=df.set_index('id')
s=df.gt(df.quantile(.90)).dot(df.columns+',').str[:-1].str.split(',')
df['c']=s
```

Comment: Great answer! Didn't think of combining `gt` and `dot`. I can't quite parse the syntax of the last part, where it looks like you cut of the last character (it's probably an added space when you concatenate with the comma), and then split the string. However, it looks like that if there are no columns above p90 a list with the empty string is returned (rather than an empty list). I figured it out using `.apply(lambda x : len(x))`. Should be put a `.strip()` somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
top_x_values = df.quantile(.9)
top_x_bool = df > top_x_values # a true / false dataframe. 
for col in top_x_bool:
    top_x_bool[col].replace(True, col, inplace=True) # replace true with col name

# Join col names to create the list you're looking for. 
df["col_list"] = top_x_bool.agg(lambda columns: ",".join(col for col in columns if col), axis=1)
```

Here's the output:

```
    col_1   col_2   col_n   col_list
0   1       21      120 
1   2       42      23  
2   55      16      54      col_1
3   4       48      12  
4   12      100     200     col_2,col_n
5   6       52      64
```